# Convert a Json String to a String

Tags: java, json, string

I have String like this. `[{"passwd":"test"}]`
I want to get the value 'test' seperatelty to a string with out converting this to a JSON. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you use JSON parser?

Comment: You want to do basic string operation?

Answer (score 2):

```
String jsonString = "[{\"passwd\":\"test\"}]";

String password = jsonString.substring(jsonString.indexOf("\":\"") + "\":\"".length(), jsonString.indexOf("\"}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String pw = [{"passwd":"test"}];
pw = pw.replaceAll("\"\\}\\]", "").split(":\"")[1];
```

This is the most easiest way and it worked for me..!